# How to pass an IEnumerable model to a partial view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

This is my layout from where I calling the partial veiw.
  This is the code where i got error.

> CS0144  Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IEnumerable'

```
<div class="fa fa-group">
  @Html.Partial("_Comment", new IEnumerable<OnlineTaxiReservationSystem.Models.Comment>)
</div>
```

This is my partial view.

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineTaxiReservationSystem.Models.Comment>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserComments)
    </th>
    @*<th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
    </th>*@
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserComments)
    </td>
    @*<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
    </td>*@
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CommentId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CommentId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CommentId })
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to achieve? What is your current model?

Comment: Exactly what the error says. Create any object that implements this interface, say List

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the code like this. Make sure to add the reference `@using System.Collections.Generic` for List.

```
<div class="fa fa-group">
    @Html.Partial("_Comment", new List<OnlineTaxiReservationSystem.Models.Comment>())
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `@model` is `IEnumerable<T>`, which is fine, but you can't create an instance of an interface. You have to pass a collection derived from `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want to pass an empty collection - you could use `new List<T>()` or `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` etc.